# jQuery launch function when register click

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple code, that bind a click on button.
But the callback inside click function is called when it is binded.

```
var showBtn = function (step) {
switch (step) {
    case '#step-one':
        $('#btnPatientAnonyme').show();
        $(".btnPopUp > input[data-type='prev']").hide();
        $(".btnPopUp > input[data-type='next']").click(showStep('#step-two'));
    break;
}
};
```

I use jQuery often and another bind click don't launch at register step. In this example, when I ask for the first step, second is shown and my need is to shown it only when the user click on button.

So why this strange behavior ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the function when you do the binding: `showStep('#step-two')`

If you want to pass additional information to your method, then you need to need to use `$.trigger`. This will let you invoke the click event and pass in the extra selector:

```
$(".btnPopUp > input[data-type='next']").trigger("click", "#step-two");
```

You will need to have already bound the click event to the popup.

So, the full code would look something like this:

```
$(".btnPopUp > input[data-type='next']").click(showStep);

var showBtn = function (step) {
    switch (step) {
        case '#step-one':
            $('#btnPatientAnonyme').show();
            $(".btnPopUp > input[data-type='prev']").hide();
            $(".btnPopUp > input[data-type='next']").trigger("click", "#step-two");
            break;
    }
};

function showStep(event, selector) { ... }
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zfya10dk/)

---

It looks like maybe you are wanting to conditionally attach the event with a parameter as opposed to triggering it. I mis-read the OP. You can attach with additional information "to-go-in" by using `$.on`:

```
$(".btnPopUp > input[data-type='next']").on("click", null, "#step-two", showStep);

function showStep(event) { ... }; // selector would be in event.data
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfya10dk/1/) for using `$.on`.

Comment: Yes, but if I trigger the function in the switch case, I have the same behavior. So, how to register the extra parameter without trigger the function ?

Comment: I'mn not sure I understand what you mean. I updated my answer with a better explanation of how the code should be structured. The click event needs to be bound in order for you to be able to trigger it. Once it is bound, you can use `$.trigger` to force the event to fire, and send in extra information. The update also includes a Fiddle example.

Comment: Your example is good but my need is to "register" in switch case a "next button" (when I hit step one, then next button will be step two, ...) and not trigger the button until the user click on the button "next". So if I use this method, step two is shown when I ask step one.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking for now. I have added an alternative answer using `$.on`.